# Java - Validation of TextField

Tags: java, textfield

**(SOLVED) Issue 1:** I am trying to add a simple verification to my 2 TextFields by checking its values. However, with this code below, I think whats happening is that the `try/catch` is called as the program starts up (which I tested with the `System.out.println()` code), therefore always resulting in an error. How can I make it such that this is called only after button `'Finish'` is pressed?
**(UNSOLVED) Issue 2:** Following on from my first issue, how can I make it such that if either my `if` or my `try/catch` returns an 'error', then pressing the `'Finish'` button doesn't end the code?

**Code:**

```
    Dialog<Pair<String, Integer>> dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.setTitle("Add new values");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Please input name and number");
    ButtonType finishButton = new ButtonType("Finish", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(finishButton, ButtonType.CANCEL);
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);

    TextField name = new TextField();
    name.setPromptText("Name");
    TextField size = new TextField();
    number.setPromptText("Number");

    grid.add(new Label("Name:"), 0, 1);
    grid.add(eventName, 1, 1);
    grid.add(new Label("Number:"), 0, 3);
    grid.add(eventSize, 1, 3);
    dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

    //verification code below
    if (eventName.getText() == null || eventName.getText() == "") {
        grid.add(new Label("Name is required!"), 0, 0);
    }
    try {
        int size = Integer.parseInt(eventSize.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        grid.add(new Label("Size is required!"), 0, 1);
        System.out.println("Test failed");
    }
```

This is the code I am trying to learn off from: [Here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/#custom-login-dialog)

Comment: Do you have this verification code in an `ActionListener`? If you add it to an `ActionListener`, and add that to a button you should be OK.

Comment: Right now, I have the button which opens this dialog window set to implement `EventHander<ActionEvent>`, if that's what you mean, and you want me to change into ActionListener. Otherwise I have no idea what you mean sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you must compare Strings using the `.equals()` method. I believe, but am not 100% certain, that the check for null is unnecessary. So, change:

```
if (eventName.getText() == null || eventName.getText() == "")
```

to

```
if (eventName.getText().equals(""))
```

I am unfamiliar with the `Dialog` class. However, when I need to implement something like this I like to use `JDialog`, and put it in a while loop:

```
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
    JTextField nameField = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField numberField = new JTextField(5);
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
    JLabel numberLabel = new JLabel("Number");

    p.add(nameLabel);
    p.add(nameField);
    p.add(numberLabel);
    p.add(numberField);

    while(true){
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, p, "Please enter Name and Number.", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
            if(nameField.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Invalid input!");
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
```

This code should guide you on how you might be able to check for different inputs, and validate them accordingly. See [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) for more details on the different dialogs you can open.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: As for `.equals()` I tried it and it still doesn't work. For issue 2, what I mean is that when pressing the button on the dialog, it will close the dialog. I want it to not close if the two `TextFields` don't have valid input.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this will help but i made a button that sounds like what your trying to do

```
//taking input from pop up box
JTextField InputPosX = new JTextField(5);
JTextField InputNegX = new JTextField(5);
JTextField InputY = new JTextField(5);
JPanel ChangeAxisPanel = new JPanel();
ChangeAxisPanel.add(new JLabel("Max X:"));
ChangeAxisPanel.add(InputPosX);
ChangeAxisPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); // a spacer
ChangeAxisPanel.add(new JLabel("Min X:"));
ChangeAxisPanel.add(InputNegX);
ChangeAxisPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); // a spacer
ChangeAxisPanel.add(new JLabel("Y:"));
ChangeAxisPanel.add(InputY);


int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ChangeAxisPanel, 
    "Please Enter X and Y Values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    //if ok is pressed
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

        if(!(InputPosX.getText().isEmpty())){

          defaultPosX=Integer.parseInt(InputPosX.getText());
        }
        if(!(InputNegX.getText().isEmpty())){

          defaultNegX=Integer.parseInt(InputNegX.getText());
        } 
        if(!(InputY.getText().isEmpty())){
          defaultY=Integer.parseInt(InputY.getText());
         }
}
}
});
```

most of this was gathered from 
[Here](http://www.java2s.co) its a good link for gui input windows. also if you are looking for a simpler method you may want to look into jbutton's you can use it to call this window

[Jbutton](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_jbutton.htm)

anyways hope this helped

Comment: Although I wasn't trying to use JTextField, your answer did give me a hint to solving my first issue. I had to check the results by doing `Optional<Pair<String, Integer>> result = dialog.showAndWait();` and then checking if `result` was present. Thanks!